# How to take a picture from default camera app using key ACTION_DOWN?

Tags: android, android-service, android-6.0-marshmallow, keyevent

I am working on Android M (6.0). In my service, I call the default camera app using the intent:

```
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "myFile.jpg");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        try {
            getApplication().startActivity(intent);
        } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In my default camera app., I can press the physical key `ACTION_DOWN` to take the picture. My question is that how can I call the key `ACTION_DOWN` using programmatically. I tried some ways but they did not work (without root). On other hands, how can we take a picture without press anything in the GUI or the physical button in the phone?

**Fist method:**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " +
     Integer.toString(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN));
```

**Second method**

```
BaseInputConnection mInputConnection = new BaseInputConnection(this, true);
KeyEvent down = new KeyEvent(now, now, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME, 0);
mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(down);
```

**Third method (not good because it needs to root phone)**

```
Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
m_Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync( KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN );
```

Comment: "My question is that how can I call the key ACTION_DOWN using programmatically" -- you can't. If you want to take a picture, execute the code from the first code snippet in your question.

Comment: so, are you talking about to inyect Key down events programmatically?

Comment: @uelordi: I want to perform the action key down using code.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Some guys said to me we can control the taking picture process using the code, instead of press any button in the GUI or the phone

Comment: "Some guys said to me we can control the taking picture process using the code" -- um, no. You cannot inject key events into other apps, for blindingly obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

> how can we take a picture without press anything in the GUI or the physical button in the phone?

Use the camera APIs directly, rather than `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but the customer does not want to make the new Activity. He only wants call the default app.

Comment: @user8430: Then you will have to let the user click the button to take the picture. There are ~2 billion Android devices, running hundreds of different camera apps. None have to have an API to allow you to take a picture without user interaction, and none have to have some standardized UI for the user to take a picture (so your hacks would not work even if they were possible from a security standpoint).

Comment: @CommonsWave: He wants to take the picture automatically. It will take the picture every 5 seconds. We can make a function running in the service to call the function that allows taking the picture after every 5 seconds but I do not know the detail inside the function

Comment: @user8430: "He wants to take the picture automatically" -- then use the camera APIs directly, as I described in my answer. You cannot take pictures using device-supplied/user-chosen camera apps without the user's involvement.

Comment: Do you have any document to verify that we cannot control the default app from programmatically? It is very useful to me to inform to customer that that work is impossible

Comment: Please give me any office document to prove that we cannot control the default camera app. I would like to accept your answer